# jython standalone jar with reduced package list?

Tags: java, python, jython

The [new version of Jython 2.7.0 standalone](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) weighs in at 36155 KB; the previous released version 2.5.3 is 14005 KB.

Is there any way to safely remove functionality from the .jar file, if certain Python packages are not needed? I want to use the updated Jython release but the file size is an issue now, much more so than 2.5.3.

Comment: in particular the [`icu`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/1.9.2) implementation alone adds 10160kB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Jython developer mailing list:

> Yes, sorry about that. We are focused on correctness first, then we
>   will go and trim down in subsequent 2.7.x releases, where x > 0. A
>   huge chunk of that additional bloat is supporting unicodedata and the
>   corresponding ICU4J jar we now use.
>
> It should be a straightforward matter of programming to remove this
>   ICU4J dependency. Possibly this and other optimizations, especially
>   startup time, would be suitable for a Google Summer of Code student,
>   given that we are planning to participate this summer.

Answer (score 1):

the reason it is bigger is that in the new version the compiled class files are included in the Lib folder.

see http://bugs.jython.org/issue1403 for a discussion

In the last entry there is a post where the speedup is measured with all class files removed from the Lib and included. So I conclude that it should be possible to remove the class files from the jar and zip it up again for a smaller package.

Comment: sounds like there should be a slimmer version of the .jar file in which you can install .py$class files in an application data directory. (so they don't have to be built every time, but they also don't have to be distributed with the .jar file)