# Reduce size of Jython jar? --- (35Mb)

Tags: java, jar, jython

The standalone Jython jar is quite large, and most of it is unnecessary. Is there a smaller version of it somewhere?

Relevant question: [jython standalone jar with reduced package list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337317/jython-standalone-jar-with-reduced-package-list)